# Create a database to store list of links inside sections

Tags: database, typescript, postgresql, database-design, orm

I am developing an app that needs to display lists of links, where each link can optionally be inside a section.

For example:

**"List of web development videos" - List title**

- **"Back End Development" -  Section title**

  - https://youtube.com/video32/ddd - url1
  - https://youtube.com/video34/ddd - url2
- **"Front End Development" - Section 2 Title**

  - https://youtube.com/video36/ddd - url3
  - https://youtube.com/video38/ddd - url4

I'm working with PostgreSQL and Typeorm.

I'm wondering how should I approach this in order to be able to maintain the order of the sections within the list, and the URLs within the section when fetching the data from the database.

Currently, I'm thinking about creating a separate table for each entity or storing the whole thing as an HTML directly into the List table.

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By all means, choose a normalized database model. Create a table `list` for the lists, a table `section` with a foreign key to `list` for the sections and a table `link` with a foreign key to `section` for the links.

You can construct the resulting HTML on the client or in SQL in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you think about creating a list, and link tables, and another junction table of links_lists that has an additional field of title and id, so when a link belongs to a list, it inserted into the junction table, and now it has an additional title and id which can be treated as a section in which many other links can belong

Comment: That would make sense only if a `link` could belong to several `list`s.